# Python hosting, what is the link between a local program and a hosted one?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, openshift

I understand my previous question is too broad, here I am trying to narrow it down.

If I have already wrote a python program that runs locally on my computer,
and I am trying to set up for it to run hosted by OpenShift(I guess google app engine is similar, PS. it also seems that google app engine is better documented). What do I need to modify on my python file to make it suitable for that purpose?

The browser UI not really required  at this moment.
The project on my mind could be categorized as web-crawler type and output by sending email summary to myself.

(background)I am a windows user and I am trying to learn git.

Thank you very much!

The following is the previous version, it helps to understand my thought process, but you don't need to answer the questions in it.

==========================

I am a python user and all my programs ran on my computer, I have never hosted my program on another website. Now I am wondering, what would be the main difference in a hosted python program and a local python program?

The project I have in mind is a script that pull stock data, plug into a selection algorithm and send email alert to myself if an alert is triggered. browser UI is not required at this moment. The motivation of having it "on" the cloud" is that I don't need to keep my own computer running all the time. (I am thinking OpenShift or Google App Engine)

I have the "local" version of this program ready. But I am really lost as to how far away this is from the "hosted" version. I have the myApp.py, what is next?

Thank you very much!

Comment: That's a good question, but not for this site. Would work perfectly for https://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think I should read on flask or bottle, they are the framework to make a local program into a web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start with the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction), right?

Note: AppEngine is build around the notion that everything is a HTTP request: all code is run to serve a HTTP request.

In your case you'd do something like this:

1. Configure the [cron service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) to invokes your code every n minutes.
2. Write [a handler](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld) called by cron service. Note: since it does not serve a user request it does not need to return any content (html).
3. In this handler use [Url Fetch](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/) to fetch data from other sites and run your algorithm.
4. You might want to [save data to datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingdatastore) via [NDB API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/). Note: file system is read-only, you can not save to files.
5. Create a [basic web page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld), where you show results. Might want to add [authentication](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/).

Comment: GEA is better documented than OpenShift
I did not find much useful info from OpenShift, 
but there are a lot more from Google, thanks for pointing that out!